# Ассемблер в VS C++. Можно ли учить, встраивая в cpp проекты

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Очень хочется попробовать ассемблер "просто чтобы знать", вопрос вот в чем:
Безопасно ли использовать asm в cpp коде?
Есть ли у встраивания ассемблерного кода дополнительные меры (модификаторы) защиты (системы и железа)?

Еще буду признателен за короткие примеры использования asm.

Comment: У меня вопрос:  а зачем?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan *"просто чтобы знать"*. Лично мне представляется достаточно уважительной причиной :) - куда более уважительной, чем "просто чтобы сдать"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можете не бояться, испортить что-то аппаратное при современных операционных системах - вряд ли вам удастся даже при очень большом желании...

Пример? Ну, например :)

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    _asm {
        mov eax,a
        mov ebx,b
        add eax,ebx
        mov a,eax
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    cout << sum(5,6) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Непосредственно в C++ коде использовать встраиваемый (inline) ассемблер крайне затруднительно из-за непоняток с ABI. Собственно из этих соображений синтаксис `asm("…")` VS не поддерживает, а нестандартное расширение `_asm { … }` осталось только на 32 битной платформе для обратной совместимости.

Так что фактически единственной формой использования ассемблера в С++ коде на сегодняшний день стали интринсики компилятора. А для использования его напрямую стоит поставить соотв. инструменты, например NASM.